# Writing inside the nodes of a matrix shift them

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-matrix

Hello helpful community,

I am faced with an issue while using a matrix of nodes in Tikz. When I write something in the nodes, they shift.

Here is a MWE :

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes,nodes={minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm,draw,very thin, },draw]
    {  
        {} & {00} & {01} & {11} & {10}\\
         {} & {} & {} & {} & {}\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And its output :

[image: TableauDeKarnaugh]

If you haven't tried online editing for latex, you should give a try to overleaf, here is my code on there : https://www.overleaf.com/read/hdpwgkdpqrtp

Comment: add `anchor=center` inside `nodes={` definition. By default a `matrix of nodes` changes their anchor to `base` , so empty and non empty nodes show different positions.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and good answer, I couldn't find the same question but it has been asked before it seems.